# Wrong value from XML

Tags: jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I have XML like this:

```
<Result>
    <Tours>
            <Tour>
        
        <id>116112250590@804</id>

        <operatorId>2672</operatorId>

        <cityId>1000</cityId>
        <countryId>12</countryId>
        <roomSizeId>14</roomSizeId>

        <departure>2020-09-16</departure>
        <arrival>2020-09-23</arrival>
        <duration>7</duration>
        <ticket>1</ticket>
        <directFlight>false</directFlight>
.............
```

Trying get value from id node Result > Tours > Tour > ID
data is parsed XML with ajax

```
$(data).find("Tour").each(function () {
        if ($(this).find("directFlight").text() == 'false') {
            var directFlight = "с пересадкой";
        } else {
            var directFlight = "прямой";
        }
        $("#tours").append('<div class="col-12">'+
            '<div class="card mb-4 shadow tour">'+
                '<div class="row no-gutters">'+
                    '<div class="col-md-3 main-image" style="background-image:url(http:' + $(this).find("Allocation>PreviewPhoto>url").text() + ');">'+
                        '<div class="rating p-2 rounded"><i class="far fa-star mr-2"></i>' + $(this).find("Allocation>rate").text() + '</div>'+
                        '<div class="price p-2 rounded">' + $(this).find("price").text() + '<i class="fas fa-ruble-sign ml-2"></i></div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="col-md-9">'+
                        '<div class="row no-gutters">'+
                            '<div class="col-md-7">'+
                                '<div class="card-body py-2">'+
                                    '<h5 class="card-title m-0">' + $(this).find("Allocation>name").text() + '</h5>'+
                                    '<span class="text-muted">' + $(this).find("Resort>name").text() + ' , ' + $(this).find("ResortPlace>name").text() + '</span>'+
                                '</div>'+
                                '<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">'+
                                    '<li class="list-group-item"><span class="text-muted">Номер:</span> ' + $(this).find("RoomSize>name").text() + ' (' + $(this).find("RoomSize>description").text() + ')</li>'+
                                    '<li class="list-group-item"><span class="text-muted">Вид:</span> ' + $(this).find("RoomView>name").text() + ' (' + $(this).find("RoomView>description").text() + ')</li>'+
                                    '<li class="list-group-item"><span class="text-muted">Питание:</span> ' + $(this).find("Meal>name").text() + ' (' + $(this).find("Meal>description").text() + ')</li>'+
                                    '<li class="list-group-item"><span class="text-muted">Тип номера:</span> ' + $(this).find("RoomType>name").text() + ' (' + $(this).find("RoomType>description").text() + ')</li>'+
                                '</ul>'+
                            '</div>'+
                            '<div class="col-md-5 border-left">'+
                                '<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">'+
                                    '<li class="list-group-item"><span class="text-muted">Вылет:</span> ' + $(this).find("departure").text() + ' (ночей: ' + $(this).find("duration").text() + ')</li>'+
                                    '<li class="list-group-item"><span class="text-muted">Перелет:</span> ' + directFlight + ' </li>'+
                                    '<li class="list-group-item"><span class="text-muted">Туроператор:</span> ' + $(this).find("Operator>name").text() + ' </li>'+
                                '</ul>'+
                                '<div class="text-center mt-3">'+
                                    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary tour-modal" data-id="' + $(this).find("id").text() + '">Подробнее</button>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</div>'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
        '</div>');
```

My id value in XML 116112250590@804 but after append id = 116112250590@80410001226721471250673211382422

Update: added my full append code
Here screenshot: [image: screenshot]

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Correct id number.

Comment: So you have more than one `Tour` and appending text doesn't give any separation from prior text

Comment: But all other data is displayed normally. Why only ID have additional value after display?

Comment: Because it is finding all the other elements with Id in it as well, you are getting a collection of elements back.

Comment: Why? I use each function with $(this).find("id").text(). I added full code

Answer (score 0):

I found solution using .first() before .text(). Dont know why .text() didnt work correct.